# Return list of indices sorted by their value and then position if tied

Tags: python

I'm facing this problem while learning python:

I coded a function that generates a list of scores based on input (where I use the index to refer to the players), for example:

```
scores = [5, 15, 0, 25, 20, 15]
```

I want to create a ranking list of the indices in descending order, and in case there are players with the same score, rank those by who has a lower index. For the example above I want this returned:

```
ranking = [3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 2]
```

My closest solution was to sort it and then get the index of each value like:

```
ranking = [ranking.index(x) for x in sorted(ranking, reverse=True)]
```

But this gets the index of the first x it meets so it returns

```
[3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 2]
```

ignoring the players with tied values. Is there a way to do this just in pure python? no libraries or anything.

Comment: this question already had an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786379/1046007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the list of indices using the values as a key:

```
sorted(range(len(scores)), key=scores.__getitem__, reverse=True)
```

Another way would be to sort the tuple of `(rank, index)` and extract the second element:

```
[x[1] for x in sorted((x[::-1] for x in enumerate(scores)), reverse=True)]
```

Both algorithms are more efficient than doing linear search for each element using `index`.

Comment: with the addition of the `reverse=True` argument

Comment: Noted and updated

Comment: Yes, the first algorithm works perfectly! Although the second might be something I could understand easier it seems in case of a tie it returns indices in descending order unlike the first method.

Comment: @7madaGIH. Sorting is stable in python, do you'll get the right result with `range(len(scores))[::-1]`